# No audio from S/PDIF optical output on Realtek ALC1200 onboard audio (MSI B550 motherboard)

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, motherboard

I have an MSI B550M Mortar motherboard which has Realtek ALC1200 onboard audio. Currently running Windows 7 x64.

I'm trying to use the S/PDIF optical output with Logitech speakers but I'm not getting any sound output at all no matter what formats I test, or what settings I apply.

Additionally, I only see options for `2 channel` output formats whereas there should be `5.1 channel` options to chose from, too.

The speakers and optical cable are confirmed working with my old motherboard's onboard audio.

The Hardware Ids of the MSI B550M's ALC1200 audio device are:

```
HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0B00&SUBSYS_1462EC94&REV_1000
HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0B00&SUBSYS_1462EC94
```

Things I have already tried:

- Latest "Univeral" Realtek audio drivers from their site (R2.82)
- Older Realtek drivers which worked with an Asus motherboard (R2.80)
- Drivers from a different MSI motherboard with similar onboard audio for Windows 7 (driver v6.0.1.8619)
- Drivers from a totally different mobo (Asrock) which uses the same chip as mine (driver v6.0.9132.1)

  *N.B. in this case, the driver package contains the exact same hardware ID string as mine so it *should* definitely be compatible*

An extremely helpful driver modder has been trying to help me on [a Techpowerup forum thread](https://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/help-needed-cant-get-realtek-alc1200-working-on-msi-b550m-motherboard-under-windows-7.281211/) but so far I've had no success.

Any suggestions are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The motherboard must have had a fried audio chip. I noticed there was no red light from optical port and even the analog 3.5mm speaker outputs refused to work when I tried using those instead of S/PDIF out.

I replaced the motherboard with an identical but working one. I then found modified drivers from a TechPowerUp forum user `dvojinov` which finally enabled DTS/DDL and it works!

The drivers which finally worked for me are: http://sharemods.com/dmwlfqpe2h66/Realtek_HDA_6.0.1.8272_DTS_DDL_experimental.zip.html

I detailed the full procedure here: https://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/help-needed-cant-get-realtek-alc1200-working-on-msi-b550m-motherboard-under-windows-7.281211/post-4508041